# Using rand write a program that "throws" a dice for x amount of times

Tags: php

Using rand write a program that "throws" a dice for x amount of times.

Where x is a variable in your program, while "throwing" the dice your program should store how many times each value appeared, then print the number of occurrences for each number.

For example, this program throwed a dice for 5 times and these are the values that appeared 1 5 5 6 3. which means the program will print the follwing at the end.

```
<?php

$dice_count = 1;
$dice_roll = 5;
while ($dice_count<= 6) {
   $dice_roll = rand(1, 5);
   if ($dice_roll <= 5) {
      echo "$dice_count occured $dice_roll time(s) <br />";
         }
   $dice_count += 1;
   }
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having with the code?

Comment: This looks like homework

Comment: For example, this program throwed a dice for 5 times and these are the values that appeared 1 5 5 6 3. which means the program will print the follwing at the end. 1 occurred 1 time(s)
2 occurred 0 time(s)
3 occurred 1 time(s)
4 occurred 0 time(s)
5 occurred 2 time(s)
6 occurred 1 time(s)

Comment: so my problem is the number of times. I solve the first part by counting the dice (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) but I can't solve the number of times.

Comment: yes, it is homework but after I submit the answer, the teacher said you can try more and more then you can serach for some example in php.net or stack overflow. if you don't find any answer, you can share your question

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$count = 5;
$throws = [];

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $roll = rand(1, 6);

    if(isset($throws[$roll]))
    {
        $throws[$roll]++;
    }
    else
    {
        $throws[$roll] = 1;
    }
}

foreach($throws as $throw => $times)
{
echo $throw occured $times
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, Domain for your kindly support. I  appreciate but can I make it like : 1 occurred 1 time(s)
2 occurred 0 time(s)
3 occurred 1 time(s)
4 occurred 0 time(s)
5 occurred 2 time(s)
6 occurred 1 time(s) (in case I throwed the dice 5 times)